# pg_restore fails when PGDATA is a mounted volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, docker-volume, podman

```bash
$ podman exec -u postgres mycontainer bash -c "pg_restore -v -U app -d mydb --no-owner < /tmp/backup.pgsql"
```

This works fine when PGDATA is **not** a mounted volume. As soon as I mount PGDATA with `podman run -dt -v ./dev_data/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ docker.io/library/postgres:13-alpine`, `pg_restore` fails with hundreds of these errors

```bash
LOG:  out of file descriptors: No file descriptors available; release and retry
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY public.account_emailaddress
        ADD CONSTRAINT account_emailaddress_email_key UNIQUE (email);
...
...
...
ERROR:  could not stat directory "base/16386": No file descriptors available
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY public.account_emailaddress
        ADD CONSTRAINT account_emailaddress_email_key UNIQUE (email);
...
...
...
... [after 7-8 minutes]
...
...
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-11-17 20:18:43 UTC
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 0/15D4980
FATAL:  could not stat directory "base/16386": No file descriptors available
CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 0/163D050 for Storage/CREATE: base/16386/16519
LOG:  startup process (PID 171) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

When pgdata is a mounted volume, normal `psql` commands works fine though - meaning `mycontainer` can write to the host mac-os directory. `mycontainer` stays alive and connections works fine from the app container. Soon after the `pg_restore` fails, within 7-8 minutes the container exits.

```
podman version 4.3.1
```

`ulimit -a` on mycontainer postgres:13-alpine

```bash
core file size (blocks)         (-c) unlimited
data seg size (kb)              (-d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size (blocks)              (-f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7257
max locked memory (kb)          (-l) 8192
max memory size (kb)            (-m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
POSIX message queues (bytes)    (-q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size (kb)                 (-s) 8192
cpu time (seconds)              (-t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4194304
virtual memory (kb)             (-v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

`ulimit -a` on podman machine

```bash
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) 7257
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) 8192
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) 1024
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                  (-r) 0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) 7257
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                          (-x) unlimited
```

`ulimit -a` on host mac os Ventura 13

```bash
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8176
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       5333
-n: file descriptors                256
```

Comment: I certainly looks like you're running out of file descriptors, but your limit seems high enough. Perhaps compare `ulimit` inside the container to that outside. This very similar bug report seems to have been due to some unidentified user process never releasing file handles: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14648

Comment: I run the same commands on docker with same volume mount of pgdata - never had this issue. Ulimit on my host macos is pretty high.

Comment: I suspect docker doesn't have any such limits due to running as root.

Comment: added more `ulimit` outputs.

Comment: I increased the mac os open files with `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536` and re-created the container. Still getting the same errors on pg_restore.